# Rules for arranging people age wise and gender wise

Tags: jess

This is my whole program for sorting people gender wise and age wise. The older should come before younger and the female should come male.

```
(deftemplate person  (slot gender)  
                (slot age (type INTEGER))   
                (slot name))


(deffacts initial-phase
   (phase choose-gender)
(phase choose-age)
(phase choose-name))

; ********
; DEFFUNCTIONS
; ********

(deffunction ask-start-again ()
  (printout t "Enter another person? (y/n) ")
  (if (eq (read) y) then
    (assert (phase choose-gender)
    (phase choose-age)
    (phase choose-name))))


;RULES

(defrule gender-select
    (phase choose-gender)
    =>
    (printout t "what is your gender (Male: m "
        "Female: f)? ")
    (assert (gender-select (read))))

(defrule good-gender-choice
   ?phase <- (phase choose-gender)
   ?choice <- (gender-select ?gender&:(or (eq ?gender m) (eq ?gender f)))
   =>
   (retract ?phase ?choice)
(assert (gender ?gender))
   (assert (phase select-age)))

(defrule bad-gender-choice 
   ?phase <- (phase choose-gender)
   ?choice <- (gender-select ?player&~m&~f)
   =>
   (retract ?phase ?choice)
   (assert (phase choose-gender))
   (printout t "Choose m or f." crlf))


(defrule age-select
   (phase select-age)
   =>
   (printout t "What is your age? ")
   (assert (age-select (read))))

(defrule good-age-choice
   ?phase <- (phase select-age)
   ?choice <- (age-select ?age&:(integerp ?age)
                                &:(> ?age 0))
   =>
   (retract ?phase ?choice)
   (assert (age ?age))
(assert (phase select-name)))

(defrule bad-age-choice
   ?phase <- (phase select-age)
   ?choice <- (age-select ?age&:(or (not (integerp ?age))
                                      (<= ?age 0)))
   =>
   (retract ?phase ?choice)
   (assert (phase select-age))
   (printout t "Choose an integer greater than zero."
               crlf))

(defrule name-select
   (phase select-name)
   =>
   (printout t "What is your name? ")
   (assert (name-select (read))))

(defrule good-name-choice
   ?phase <- (phase select-name)
   ?choice <- (name-select ?name&:(or (not (integerp ?name))))
   =>
   (retract ?phase ?choice)
   (assert (name ?name)))

(defrule bad-name-choice
   ?phase <- (phase select-name)
   ?choice <- (name-select ?name&:(integerp ?name))
   =>
   (retract ?phase ?choice)
   (assert (phase select-name))
   (printout t "Please enter a name."
               crlf))

(defrule old-female-first
?gender <- (gender f)  
?age <- (age ?b&:(> ?b 35))
     =>
   (printout t "Person is female & older. This Person must go first!" crlf)
   (retract ?gender)
   (retract ?age)
   (ask-start-again))

(defrule young-female-third
?gender <- (gender f)  
?age <- (age ?age&:(<= ?age 35))
   =>
   (printout t "Person is female & younger. This Person must go after older males!" crlf)
   (retract ?gender)
   (retract ?age)
   (ask-start-again))

(defrule old-male-second
?gender <- (gender m)  
?age <- (age ?a&:(> ?a 35))
   =>
   (printout t "Person is male & older. This Person must go after older females!" crlf)
   (retract ?gender)
   (retract ?age)
   (ask-start-again))

(defrule young-male-last
 ?gender <- (gender m)
?age <- (age ?age&:(<= ?age 35))
   =>
   (printout t "Person is male & younger. This Person must go after younger females!" crlf)
   (retract ?gender)
   (retract ?age)
   (ask-start-again))


(defrule print-all-persons
  (declare (salience -1000))
  (person (name ?name) (age ?age) (gender ?gender))
=>
  (printout t ?name ?age ?gender crlf))

(reset)
(run)
```

The code is not giving any error but also not getting expected output.

Comment: I am a beginner at Jess. I am trying to learn the rules and do a project. I need to enter multiple people details and compare all of them. and then sort according to age and gender. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that much is missing, first the assert of a `(phase goose-gender)`. - You need to keep a triple of  gender/age/name-select facts and create a person fact from them; then retract and insert another `(phase choose-gender)`. You'll need a "gender" `q` for terminating the input. - One cannot "sort" facts in memory, but one can find them in a certain order and insert them in a list (if that's what you want to do), or print them (which appears to be likely, given rule "print-solution".

Comment: Thank you Laune. I will put three of each gender/age/name select facts. How do i create a gender 'q'? How do I save the information given for one person so that I can compare?

Comment: Forget the 'q' - there is the function ask-start-again. --- You create a `person` fact from the gender-/age-/name-select facts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code.

```
(deftemplate Person (slot gender) (slot name) (slot age(type INTEGER)))

(deffunction validateName (?personname)
    (bind ?stringLen (str-length ?personname))  
    (bind ?index 1)
        (while (>= ?stringLen ?index)
            (bind ?currentChar (sub-string ?index ?index ?personname))
            (bind ?ASCIIValue (asc ?currentChar))
            (if (and (>= ?ASCIIValue 0) (<= ?ASCIIValue 64)) then (return 0))
            (if (and (>= ?ASCIIValue 91) (<= ?ASCIIValue 96)) then (return 0))
            (if (>= ?ASCIIValue 123) then (return 0))

            (bind ?index (+ ?index 1))
        )
        (return 1)
)

(deffunction getGender()
    (printout t "Enter Gender (M|F) : ")
    (bind ?localGender (read))

    (if (or (eq (upcase ?localGender) M) (eq (upcase ?localGender) F)) 
    then 
         (return ?localGender)
    )
    (printout t "Invalid Gender... Try Again..." crlf crlf)
    (return (getGender()))
)

(deffunction getName()
    (printout t "Enter Name : ")
    (bind ?localName (readline))

    (if (eq (validateName ?localName) 1) then (return ?localName))

    (printout t "Invalid Name... Try Again..." crlf crlf)
    (return (getName()))
)

(deffunction getAge()
    (printout t "Enter Age : ")
    (bind ?localAge (read))

    (if (integerp ?localAge) then (if (> ?localAge 0) then (return ?localAge)))

    (printout t "Invalid Age... Try Again..." crlf crlf)
    (return (getAge()))
)

(deffunction showAllPesron()
    (printout t crlf"-------------------------------" crlf)
    (printout t "         Person List           " crlf)
    (printout t "-------------------------------" crlf)
    (printout t "Gender |  Age  |  Name" crlf)
    (printout t "-------------------------------" crlf)
)

(deffunction getPersonDetail()
    (printout t crlf)
    (bind ?gender (getGender()))
    (bind ?name (getName()))
    (bind ?age (getAge()))

    (if (eq (upcase ?gender) M) then (assert (Person (gender M) (name ?name) (age ?age))))
    (if (eq (upcase ?gender) F) then (assert (Person (gender F) (name ?name) (age ?age))))  
    (printout t crlf)
)

(defrule show-person-order
   ?P <- (Person (gender ?gender1) (name ?name1) (age ?age1))
   (not (Person (age ?age2&:(> ?age2 ?age1))))
   =>
   (printout t ?gender1"         "?age1"      "?name1 crlf)
   (retract ?P)
)

(deffunction main()

    (printout t "Add another person? (Y|N) : ")
    (bind ?addAnother (read))

    (if (eq (upcase ?addAnother) Y) then (getPersonDetail()) (main()))  
)

(getPersonDetail())
(main())
(showAllPesron())
(run)
(reset)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to your question which will, perhaps, not be easy to understand. However, I'll try and add lots of comments.

The fundamental idea of this "sort" is to identify person facts in the sort order: older before younger, female before male. After finding the winner fact it is retracted, so that the rule can fire again with the second best, and so on, until all person facts have been retracted.

Here is the rule in pseudo-code:

```
(defrule findFirst
   ?p1 <- (person)
   not ?p2 <- (person ranked before ?p1)
=>
   (retract ?p1))
```

Since the ranking involves more than one slot it is best written as a function which can be called with ?p1 and ?p2 as arguments. The compare
function can be written to return -1, 0 or +1, just like Java's compare methods.

```
(defrule findFirst
   ?p1 <- (person)
   (not (and ?p2 <- (person)
            (test (< (comparePerson ?p2 ?p1) 0))))
=>
   (retract ?p1))
```

It would be nice if we could write the compare function in a flexible way so that another sort order wouldn't require a complete new function. This can be done by using lambdas - anonymous deffunctions - each of which compares just one slot. Here are the ones for age and gender, assigned to globals so that they are accessible from a rule's LHS:

```
(defglobal ?*compAge* = 
  (lambda (?pa ?pb)
    (- (fact-slot-value ?pb age) (fact-slot-value ?pa age) )))

(defglobal ?*compGender* =
  (lambda (?pa ?pb)
    (- (asc (fact-slot-value ?pa gender))
       (asc (fact-slot-value ?pb gender)))))
```

(Note the reversal of ?pa and ?pb to get descending age order.) We can now write the comparePerson function, which receives two person facts (?pa, ?pb) and *a list of lambdas* ($?comp).

```
(deffunction comparePerson(?pa ?pb $?comp)
  ;; if a comparison with the first function yields a decision, return it
  (if (< ((nth$ 1 $?comp) ?pa ?pb) 0) then (return -1))
  (if (> ((nth$ 1 $?comp) ?pa ?pb) 0) then (return 1))
  ;; if this is the last function we have two equal persons: return 0
  (if (= (length$ $?comp) 1) then (return 0))
  ;; otherwise call the compare function with the remaining functions
  (return (comparePerson ?pa ?pb (rest$ $?comp))))
```

And now the rule, triggered with another value for the phase fact:

```
(defrule findFirst
  ?phase <- (phase sort-persons)
  ?p1 <- (person)
  (not (and ?p2 <- (person)
            (test (< (comparePerson ?p2 ?p1 ?*compAge* ?*compGender*) 0))))
=>
 (printout t (fact-slot-value ?p1 name) " selected" crlf)
 (retract ?p1))
```

Note: person facts are best assembled as soon as a correct name has been entered. There's no need to create and insert the `name` fact.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping Laune. It is a bit hard to understand all these things since i am just a beginner in Jess, but this was so helpful in going forward. But I am trying to learn and figure out an answer with the help of your answers. Thanks much again. Is there an email ID i can contact you. I am still getting some token errors.

Comment: You learn a lot when you have to figure out why Jess reports an error so I think you shouldn't simply email them to me. However, before you become truly desperate, post a questions on SO and add a @laune comment so I'll be aware of it quickly.

Comment: BTW, it would be a good exercise to write a deffunction that compares person facts based on age and gender without the lambda mechanism. You have the ingredients in the lambdas and the deffunction `comparePerson` so it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Hi, somehow I figured out and cleared all the errors. But the problem now is, certain rules are not getting executed. I am getting the same output as earlier but with no errors. (question edited)

Comment: The output at http://i.stack.imgur.com/uhK7j.png doesn't match the code in your question, so what am I to say?

Comment: :Sorry, my bad. I edited the code now. Please advice.

Comment: Well, this isn't as it should be - the question I answered here is gone, so my answer appears to be nonsense. What you have now is a *new* question, and should be asked as such. Please copy to a new question, and then I can restore the previous text of your question. - I have copied your edited question and will be looking at it shortly, so I can answer your new question presently.

Comment: Okay, i will ask this as new question. I will put the previous ques back so that your answer will make sense. Thank you.